# Cocoa window dragging

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask to listen to events in Cocoa:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask 
                                       handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
    NSLog(@"Dragged...");
}];
```

Though I would like to know if I'm dragging/moving a window (and which window that is, I can find the focused window though when holding command and dragging a window it doesn't get focus as far as I know.)

So, can I detect whether or not I'm dragging a window?

Update:

I now have a class: "`SATest : NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>`" in which I implement the windowDidMove method (and later perhaps windowWillMove too.) Though, now the next step would be attaching this to a window, right? So my question now is: How do I attach the delegate to all windows of all apps?

Update 2:

I now can find a list of all open windows on the screen:

```
AXUIElementRef _systemWideElement;
_systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();

CFArrayRef _windows;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues(_systemWideElement, kAXWindowsAttribute, 0, 100, &_windows);
```

Now I have to iterate over the windows, and of each get it's NSWindow so I can add my delegate to it: `[window setDelegate:self];`

Update 3: To be clear, this question is about detecting the dragging of ALL windows of ALL apps. Not only the windows of my own app.

Also, I'm very new to this event and window management stuff, so no need to keep your answer short I'm happy to read a lot :P

Thanks!
-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Benjamin the answer lies in the accessibility API. I was looking around in this for a while, even before I asked this question, but never got it to do what I wanted. I now have found a pretty nice solution.

At a high-level I do the following:

1. Listen to the mouse down event and remember both on which window you clicked and it's location.
2. Listen to the mouse up event and check if the location has changed, if so you know you moved a window

You can do something similar for the size if you also want to know if you resized. There might be a better solution, but after days of trying stuff this is the only way I got it to work the way I wanted.

Hope this helps anyone who was looking for something similar.

-Pablo

Answer (score 5):

To find out if a window is being dragged you need to have an object that acts as the delegate of the window by responding to the following messages of the *NSWindowDelegate* protocol:

1. *windowWillMove* - this tells the delegate that the window is about to move.
2. *windowDidMove* - this tells the delegate that the window has moved.

You can retrieve the NSWindow object in question by sending *object* to the notification parameter sent to these methods:

e.g.

```
NSWindow draggedWindow = [notification object];
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

**Update:**

In response to your request about getting this information for all windows the [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class provides a method which returns an array of all windows owned by the application. The typical way of getting this information is to use one of the [NSApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods to get a reference to your application object.

For example, in your app delegate (pseudocode):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSApplication * app = [aNotification object];
    // you now have a reference to your application.
    // and can iterate over the collection of windows and call
    // [window setDelegate:self]; for each window.
}
```

Note that you will need to add / remove you delegates as windows are added and removed. The best method for doing this is *– applicationDidUpdate:*.

This should be enough to get you started solving your problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, I got my class: "@interface SATest : NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>" and I implemented the windowDidMove method. Though how do I attach this to a window? (And where do I get this window from :P I'm trying to get this move thing of all windows open of all apps.)

Comment: You need to either create an instance in your nib file and Ctrl+drag from the object to the window to set it as the delegate of that window. Alternatively, you could implement <NSWindowDelegate> on your AppDelegate to save creating a new object in your nib file.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but is't this for just the windows of my own app? I'm trying to get it from other apps too. I would like to know when any window of any app currently running is moving. Though going to try some stuff out, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this will only work for your application. I have done some searching and the accessibility API gets mentioned whenever your problem comes up. I do not know anything about the accessibility API having never used it before so cannot help you further.